# C# Voice recognition error recEngine?

Tags: c#

I need to find out when the code is running the program crashes after using it for a while. I need to close the program most of the time with Task manager. 
Is there a way to fix this error? It usually says the program if not responding in the task manger box.

When i double click on the Enable voice control button, is when i get this error.

The only info I got on this was that the UI was detected some how and the error showed where it need to be fixed.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot perform this operation while the recognizer is doing recognition.

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        btnDisable.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] { "Hello","How is it hanging", "print my name Albert","print my name Francisco", "print my name Nixon", "print my name Steve", "print my name Diego" });
        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar grammer = new Grammar(gBuilder);

        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammer);
        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;


    }
```

Comment: Use your debugger....

Comment: your previous attempt contained more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798782/c-sharp-development-voice-recognition

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're performing some action which ins't allowed. It's hard to tell with the information you posted, but maybe identify your calls to the `recEngine` and see if you need to call `recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop` before said action is performed.

Comment: It's hard to explain it because i can't really upload a picture of it. I need privileges to unlock them.